# Are this steps towards improve pretrained VGG16 results correct

Tags: optimization, conv-neural-network, train

### Context

tldr you can skip to the bottom to see the question. I just add some basic information about the problem below.

I have been testing my VGG16 based network in this cases

1. Stop signs (small training set from caltech101)
2. Airplanes (larger dataset, from Caltech101 as well)

The network worked well to predict the bounding box in both cases, as well as to do binary classification. For each case, it uses a different set of output layers, and the same vgg16 body with frozen layers and pre-trained weights.

Yet these datasets are simple, with large and centered objects.

When I tackled a more realistic problem the results were still conceptually fine but quite innacurate. So I thought about a few options

- Increase the units in the head of the NN (layers I added in top of vgg16)
- Fine tune other parameters like learning rate or batch size
- Find more data (my current problem is barcode bounding box and I have about 1500 labelled images only.)
- Train the inner layers of the network

### Question

My question is about the last bullet point. I have read that different layers normally detect different information (extracted from the convolution operation), the inner layers may be more low level, the upper layers more high level.

So would it be an acceptable approach to reduce the number of parameters of the last VGG16 layers, and train these myself rather than using external weights?

Comment: Did you already try augmentation techniques on the dataset (maybe rotation/flipping/random crops can apply, it depends on your experience on the problem)? The last trial could be quite more expensive than the others, for sure. It could help to quantify "inaccurate" with some metrics, and how much it is distant from your expectation. Also an extensive hyperparameter search, (lr, number of units in each layer, number of layer, regularization and dropout...). For this latter case, extracting features and storing them could significantly speed up your process.

Comment: Interesting. No but it is a good option. Indeed the dataset isnt great, however, when I try simpler datasets, I dont get a perfect box around the say faces. For example I did caltech101 faces (all front, large faces), and still not great. I am using 3 dense output layers of 196, 112, 32 and output of 4 units. @DarioCioni

Comment: Up to now you used qualitative metrics (i.e your eye) to describe your situation, but it sure would help to compute and post some quantitative metric like AP and mAP. All the solutions you wrote can be right, and I think the best way is to perform some experimentation and choose the best solution. Also, metrics are mandatory if you want to conduct an extensive hyperparameter search on your classifier, since you need a metric to guide your optimization. I'll plan to summarize all these points in a detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you. I try to always do the simplest first, but I got stuck anyways. I generate the losses and also draw the boxes in all images to get an idea of how it works.@DarioCioni

Comment: @Ciodar found the problem. VGG on its own (a CNN) is not enough for predicting bounding boxes. It has to be used with some extra mechanism like SDD, or Window Sliding etc.